# Configruing confirmation page for download for particular directory

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, vs-web-site-project

I have links in my page which says,

```
<a href='www.mysite.com/ebooks/mybook.pdf'>Mybook</a>
```

when i click on it, there should be some download confirmation page.

Comment: You forgot the question.

Comment: oh sorry and thanks also, I'm new at this forum. I just kept on typing but didn't see whats actually going below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Here is a quick demo how to do that**

HTML

```
<a class="links" href='www.mysite.com/ebooks/mybook.pdf'>Mybook</a>
<br />
<a class="links" href='www.mysite.com/ebooks/mybook.pdf'>Mybook</a>
<br />
<a class="links" href='www.mysite.com/ebooks/mybook.pdf'>Mybook</a>
<br />
<a class="links" href='www.mysite.com/ebooks/mybook.pdf'>Mybook</a>
<br />
<a class="links" href='www.mysite.com/ebooks/mybook.pdf'>Mybook</a>

<div id="modal">
    <h3>You are going to download mybook.pdf. Are you sure?</h3>
    <button id="yes">Yes</button>
    <button id="no">No</button>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#modal {
    display: none;
    margin: 80px;
    padding: 20px;
    background: #E4E4E4;
    text-align: center;
    color: #2E3B6F;
}

#modal button {
    margin: 0 5px;
}
```

JS

```
$(function(){
    var link = '';
    $(".links").click(function(e){
        $("#modal").hide().show("slow");
        link = $(this).attr("href");    

        return false;
    });

    $("#yes").click(function(e){  
      if(link) window.location.href = link;
    });

    $("#no").click(function(e){
        $("#modal").hide("slow");
    });
});
```

Live Demo: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pjrzvB

I used jQuery but you can also made same functionality without jQuery.

**Update based on your comment. 10.11.2015**

Comment: Thanks @ruben, but what should be done in case of large no. of files on a particular directory. Like on my webserver 'www.mysite.com/ebooks/' has 100's of ebooks. Is there any way that can make this happen for anyone who clicks for pdfs file on that particular directory and it ask for confirmation . The main problem is that I've all those pdf's link on my blog(blogger) and i've hosted those all pdfs on my separate webserver i.e www.mysite.com/ebooks/ .This is why its really challenging for me.

Comment: updated check it out :)